usocket error: Error: EBADF error in Node.js when connect with Rust code
I am doing socket programming between Rust and Node.js and for that Node.js code is engine code and below is the Rust code. But when I try to run the Rust code I am getting error like Error: EBADF in Node.js.
fn pass_fd() {
    let mut local = sockaddr_un {
        sun_family: libc::AF_UNIX as libc::sa_family_t,
        sun_path: [0; 108],
  
    };

    let local_path = CString::new(unsafe {GLOBAL_VARS.socket_path.clone() } ).unwrap();
    unsafe {
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
            local_path.as_ptr(),
            local.sun_path.as_mut_ptr(),
            local_path.as_bytes().len(),
        );
         eprintln!("before unlink");

   
          eprintln!("socket  error");
      GLOBAL_VARS.server_fd = match socket(AddressFamily::Unix, SockType::Stream, SockFlag::empty(), None) {
        Ok(fd) => fd,
        Err(_) => {
            graceful_exit(Some("socket() error"));
            return;
        }
    };

   
    eprintln!("SERVER FD IS  {}", GLOBAL_VARS.server_fd);
     let path_len = local_path.as_bytes().len() + std::mem::size_of_val(&local.sun_family);
    if unsafe { libc::unlink(local_path.as_ptr()) } == -1 && Error::last_os_error().raw_os_error() != Some(libc::ENOENT) {
        graceful_exit(Some("unlink() error"));
        return;
    }
           eprintln!("bind() error");
    let addr = SockAddr::Unix(UnixAddr::new(GLOBAL_VARS.socket_path.as_str()).unwrap());
    if bind(GLOBAL_VARS.server_fd, &addr).is_err() {
        graceful_exit(Some("bind() error"));
        return;
    }
     eprintln!("listen() error");
    if listen(GLOBAL_VARS.server_fd, 5).is_err() {
        graceful_exit(Some("listen() error"));
        return;
    }

      eprintln!("before accept");
            eprintln!("beofre_wait for fd1");
    eprintln!("fn pass_fd()6666666");
    if !wait_for_fd(GLOBAL_VARS.server_fd, Duration::from_secs(15), "accept()") {
        return;
    }
}

Here when I put wait, and checked and the last log I got is  eprintln!("fn pass_fd()6666666");, and till time it hit wait_for_fd, the error in Node.js, I am getting. But the same thing is working as C++ code, i.e. when instead of Rust, I used C++, it worked.
The exact error I am getting like usocket error: Error: EBADF, USocket '../src/uwrap.cc:489'
here is the js code
start: function (webServerManager) {
    this.on('notifyNamedSocket', function(payload) {
        var uClient = new usocket.USocket();
        uClient.on('connected', function() { uClient.read(0);  });
        uClient.on('fds', function(fd) {
            if (payload.port === 3000) {
                webServerManager.connectHTTP(fd[0]);
            } else {
                webServerManager.connectHTTPS(fd[0]);
            }
            uClient.end();
        });
        uClient.on('error', function(error) {
            logger.info('[second_screen_gateway]', 'usocket error: ' + error);
        });
        uClient.connect(payload.path);
    });


If the error happens in Node.js, post your Node.js code too.

@toyotaSupra: Also, please don’t format things that are not code (e.g. names, like “Rust” and “Node.js”) as inline code.

@robertklep, here is the js code
I have added the js code

I would suggest creating a Minimal Reproducible Example.
